# I cannot create view which contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Tags: mysql, view, mysql-workbench

the data source is:

```
Start Time              Real End Time           Staff
2013-02-14 16:44:27     2013-02-14 18:44:27     P 
2013-02-14 16:44:08     2013-02-14 17:09:08     C
2013-02-14 16:42:51     2013-02-14 16:43:51     P
2013-02-14 16:31:26     2013-02-14 17:06:26     V
2013-02-14 16:04:02     2013-02-14 16:34:02     C
```

when I was using:

```
CREATE VIEW turn_times AS
SELECT staff AS name, start_time, real_end_time AS work_end_time
FROM (  SELECT staff, start_time, real_end_time
        FROM treatments 
        WHERE date(real_end_time) = curdate()
        ORDER BY real_end_time ASC) AS a
GROUP BY name
```

I got:

```
mysql #1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause
```

I want to get the following data by **using view**, is there any good solution:

```
name    start_time             work_end_time
C       2013-02-14 16:04:02    2013-02-14 16:34:02
P       2013-02-14 16:42:51    2013-02-14 16:43:51
V       2013-02-14 16:31:26    2013-02-14 17:06:26
```

I don't want to create two views for this problem, can I get the correct sql in one view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the subquery with the `ORDER BY`, did you try using an aggregate function (`MIN`) to return the `min()` date for each `staff`:

```
SELECT staff, 
  min(start_time),
  min(real_end_time)AS work_end_time
FROM treatments 
WHERE date(real_end_time) = curdate()
group by staff
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d254f/8).

Then to turn into a view:

```
CREATE VIEW turn_times AS
SELECT staff, 
  min(start_time),
  min(real_end_time)AS work_end_time
FROM treatments 
WHERE date(real_end_time) = curdate()
group by staff
```

This version above replicates the result that you provided, but if you want the end time, you might want to use the following. This will give you the actual start time for each staff and the end time:

```
CREATE VIEW turn_times AS
SELECT staff, 
  min(start_time) as start_time,
  max(real_end_time) AS work_end_time
FROM treatments 
WHERE date(real_end_time) = curdate()
group by staff
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d254f/13)

Comment: Yes, I tried using max, but it was like wrong. anyway, thanks a lot

Comment: @Victor I used `min` because you were sorting the data in ascending order. You could also have used `min(start_time)` and `max(real_end_time)`.

Comment: Hey bluefeet.. I have a similar problem.. Didn't post a question, as its kinda similar and thought it could be resolved here.. I am finding the `counts` in the subquery and then the `sums` of those `counts` in the outer query. Same error. How can I resolve it? I'll start a new question if you want me to. Thanks! :)

Comment: @CodingInCircles It would be easier to post a new question.  I can see all of the details and we won't be going back and forth in the comments.  Feel free to post the link in a comment here once you post it. :)

Comment: Hey bluefeet, sorry for the delay in putting up the question. Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232965/mysql-view-with-a-subquery. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you are using sub-query, but you can achieve similar result without sub-query

```
CREATE VIEW turn_times AS
SELECT staff AS name, 
  MIN(start_time) AS start_time,
  MAX(real_end_time) AS work_end_time,
  date(start_time) As turn_date
FROM treatments 
WHERE 
AND date(start_time) = curdate()
AND date(real_end_time) = curdate()
GROUP BY staff, date(start_time);
```